# mouse over on menu doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a HTML template and I'm facing an issue while accessing the li / ul sub menu list.
sometimes, when I click on the main menu, the list of sub menus is displayed but as soon as I'm trying to mouse over on the sub menu, it disapear...I tested it on Chrome/Firefox/IE with the same result.

I'm loading the menu on my main HTML page via JQuery like this:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //loading top menu
        $("#menuTop").load("menu_test.html");

    });
</script>
```

and here is the menu

```
<aside class="left-sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar scroll-->
        <div class="scroll-sidebar">
            <!-- Sidebar navigation-->
            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul id="sidebarnav">
                    <li class="nav-devider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-small-cap">Accueil</li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="index.jsp" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-home"></i><span class="hide-menu">Accueil</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-home-modern"></i><span class="hide-menu">Menu 1</span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="#">page1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page3</a></li>                                
                            <li><a href="#">page4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page8</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-bank"></i><span class="hide-menu">Finances </span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="#">page1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page9</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-cube-unfolded"></i><span class="hide-menu">Configuration </span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="#">page1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page5</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-forum"></i><span class="hide-menu">Forum</span></a>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="mail.jsp" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-email"></i><span class="hide-menu">Messagerie</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li> <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-settings"></i><span class="hide-menu">Paramètres</span></a>
                        <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse">
                            <li><a href="#">page1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
            <!-- End Sidebar navigation -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Sidebar scroll-->
    </aside>
```

here is a demo version [demo](http://5.39.80.220:8080/test/display_test.html)

do you know why I'm facing such issue ?

Comment: Demo link broken.

Comment: I suspect the submenu is not a child of the element you are hovering over to make it appear.  Thus when you mouse out of the menu to go to the submenu it triggers the hide for the submenu

Comment: how can I check that ul submenu is not a child of my main li menu ? I do not see any error

Comment: Given your markup I would trigger the hover effect on the parent `li` to both the menu and submenu, so mousing to the submenu will not break that hover display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually happening because there is a very small space in between the button you are hovering and the sub-menu. So when you move your mouse out of the main menu item it leaves the area entirely.

Get rid of the `top: 57px` CSS rule for

`.mini-sidebar .sidebar-nav #sidebarnav>li>ul`

Also - as a note for the future, please include your relevant CSS.

Comment: @tiamat Glad to help! In Chrome dev-tools, you can right click on an element and force the hover state which will hover the menu and let you see the issue more clearly

Comment: yes I know, but I need to improve my knowledge on css to be able to identify such issue...

Answer (score 1):

There is a gap below the main menu link. So if you move your mouse down it is no longer 'hovering' inside the li and the sub menu dissapears. close the gap and it'll work

As pointed out by Adjit, try changing the top value to:

```
top: 100%;
```